# How can I filter my records to show all records in the main table at D365 FO with X++?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++

I need to use onlookup event to filter my data based on another table in form.
I have inventsite form and 2 tables with 1:N relation in it. One of them is SitePI and other one PITrans.

Here is the scenario: I go to InventSite form and add a site named test and I go to SitePI table ( it is in the fast tab) I add records (001, 004, 005), I add another site named test2 and add records 003,006,007 for its SitePI. lastly, I go to PITrans table ( It is in the another fast tab,) and when I press the drop-down I need to able to select records that belong to SitePI table as lookup.

But I can see only the selected record.

[image: Image of my tables and issue]

I need to see 001, 004 and 005 when I select records.

Here is my code ( PICode is RefRecId for my lookup table)

```
[FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(InventSite, PITrans_PICode), FormControlEventType::Lookup)]
public static void PITrans_PICode_OnLookup(FormControl sender, FormControlEventArgs e)
{
    SysReferenceTableLookup tableLookup = SysReferenceTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(SitePI), sender);
    Query query = new Query();

    SitePI sitePI = sender.formRun().dataSource('SitePI').cursor();
    InventSite inventSite = sender.formRun().dataSource('InventSite').cursor();

    QueryBuildDataSource qbds = query.addDataSource(tableNum(SitePI));
    
    qbds.addRange(fieldNum(SitePI, PICode)).value(queryValue(sitePI.PICode));
   

    query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(SitePI)).addOrderByField(fieldNum(SitePI, PICode), SortOrder::Ascending);

    tableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(SitePI, PICode));
    
    tableLookup.parmQuery(query);
    tableLookup.performFormLookup();

    FormControlCancelableSuperEventArgs ce = e as FormControlCancelableSuperEventArgs;
    ce.CancelSuperCall();
```

I would be really appreciated it if anyone can help me.

Regards

Comment: Your range should look like `qbds.addRange(fieldNum(SitePI, InventSite)).value(queryValue(sitePI.InventSite));`

Comment: That worked. Why didn't think that before. Thank you very much. Much appreciated.

Comment: I have one more issue. While I select PI code it's okay but once I select it, it shows both PI code and Id of the selected site but I want to see only PiCode. index of SitePI table includes InventSite and PICode fields. I know that's why the system shows me these but I cannot delete InventSite from the index. Is there any way to hidden it when I select record from lookup? If you have any advise about it that would be great for me, thank you very much.